# Did God die for our sins?

Tags: life-of-jesus, islam

The question is simple but I really need an answer...
If Jesus died for our sins then the question would be how could God die?
If God didn't die and it's only the human flesh then God didn't really die for our sins it's just his human form.

I'm Muslim but I've been searching for the truth for a really long time.
If it's Islam I'm willing to stay there.
If it's Christianity I'm really willing to convert.
If it's Judaism I'm willing to convert.

Comment: You will get different answers depending on the viewpoint of the reader. A non-Trinitarian will mostly say no, while Trinitarians will probably say yes.

Comment: See if this answers your question.  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53084/if-jesus-is-god-then-how-could-he-die

Comment: @Hamza If possible, may a suggest you find a Christian you can talk to in person about this.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that this doesn't apply to all christian denominations, but probably most. When we say "dying", it's the physical body that dies. The spirit never dies in the sense of ceasing to exist, be it humans or God.

The resurrection is reuniting the spirit and body.

In resurrecting, Jesus conquered death and opened the path for all humankind to be ressurrected.

Comment: Thanks. but do you think it’s possible for God’s “spirit” ( or whatever I should call it ), that I believe to be Infinite, to be fully in a Finite body?

Comment: It is not a good idea to answer an un scoped question.

Comment: @Hamza An excellent question, but it should be asked as a separate question, not as a comment.

Comment: Thank you it's really good to feel that there are people caring for you

Comment: @Kris Sorry, you are right, but it's tempting.